# Automated jobs stopped running out of nowhere.. PDOException

Tags: php, sql-server

Can someone please help me with this? I'm new to the PDO world and I can't figure out why my automated jobs stop running out of nowhere!! Although, I believe this error may have something to do with it. Can someone please help?

```
    if($freq == 7) {
        $verifyjobsql = "select job_id from infocenter.dbo.cproc3_history where process_id = '$processid' and checkdate = '$checkdate' and process = '$process' and rundate = $therundate and quarter = $thequarter and $year = $theyear and month = $themonth and dayofmonth = $theday;";
        $verifyjobquery = mssql_query($verifyjobsql,$linkdb01);
        $verifyjobcount = mssql_num_rows($verifyjobquery);
```

Comment: Please, post the code.

Comment: It a SQL code error, review the SQL query executed at /var/www/cproc_sweeper.php(84) "`select job_id ...`"

Comment: `mssql_` functions are removed in PHP7, replace by `PDO` or `sqlsrv_` or `odbc_`

Comment: You're so new to "the PDO world" that you don't have any PDO code posted...